# How to access mdb file in windows10 by powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-access

Following the suggestion that shown in the following link,
I have created a powershell script to access the mdb file.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script/

which is:

```
    $cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
    $rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
    $cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")
```

However, i have updated my computer to windows 10 (64bit) and installed ACCESS 2016. The powershell script does not working anymore. And it shows that the 
Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not found.

I have tried to change the Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
But it does not help, as it shows the same error that the provider is not found.

Moreover, I have tried to open it with ACCESS 2016, it also does not help as it shows that can not open the database file that created in previous version.

Please help....

Comment: If your ACCESS 2016 also will not open the file, there must be something wrong with it. Do you get an error message? Can you test on another, older system to see if there it does open?

Comment: Can you share the code you're running?

Comment: @Theo Thanks to your reply. When i open it in ACCESS 2016, it shows "Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application." My old system is Windows 7 with Access 2013, which has no problem.

Comment: @Adam My code is just like the one I provided in the link.  Where the $path is the path to the mdb file. $cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")

Comment: @HansUp My MS Office should be 32bit. I would like to know how to check whether i have installed the ACE provider or not? And where should i find them in case i have not installed?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for whom reply my question. 
Finally I got insight and find the answer myself.

I search the provider from Microsoft and find the link below.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

After install the 64bit version, I can use the following code with the  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider.

```
$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = $path")
```

Answer (score 0):

If Win 10 OS 64 bits with MS Office 32bits / click2run  , use 32bits Powershell ;)